# Add many locations to Google Map?

Tags: google-maps

I have a bunch of addresses that I need to add to one of my Google Maps.

Google Maps just says to [add each and everyone of them manually](http://maps.google.com/help/maps/getmaps/plot-multi.html), but it's a lot of of work to do this manually.

Does someone know of a tool that takes a bunch of addresses as input (eg. TXT), and adds the plots in a given Google Map?

Comment: I don't have time to write a full answer right now, but you should be able to import KML files into Google Maps. A KML file is basically a plain text list of lat/long coordinates wrapped up in some XML. There should be plenty of documentation of the specs online. If you need to go from _addresses_, not so sure...

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'll check if KML means that locations are definitely imported in a given Google Map or if the user must load the KML file to view the plots.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I search for a list of cities in Google Maps?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/45735/how-can-i-search-for-a-list-of-cities-in-google-maps)

Comment: @AndrewLott it should have been the other way around. This question predates the duplicate, half a year.

Answer (score 1):

You can [use a service like BatchGeo to generate a KML file containing all your addresses](http://batchgeo.com/features/google-earth-kml/) and then [show those locations on a Google Map](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/296/18670)