# How can I search for a list of cities in Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps

I would like to see those cities marked in Google Maps:

> Bonn, Bornheim, Dorsten, Dortmund, Essen, Feldhausen, Grevenbroich, Hallenberg, Koeln, Krefeld, Moers, Muenster, Neuss, Neviges, Velbert, Walberberg, Wuppertal, Wuppertal

Can I somehow enter that list in the Maps search bar to see those cities all at once?

I thought of something like :

> from Bonn over Bornheim, over Dorsten to Wuppertal, Germany

but that search-string doesent work in Google Maps like this

Comment: Related:  [See multiple locations on a google map](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/36672/add-many-locations-to-google-map)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't mind doing this outside of the normal maps.google.com interface, there's a site which lets you [Plot multiple locations on Google Maps](http://gmaps.kaeding.name/). You can even save a [custom link](http://gmaps.kaeding.name/saved/freifunk_nrw) to the map you've created.

If you don't mind doing a bit of coding, you can pull in the list of locations from a [Google Spreadsheet](http://googlemapsapi.blogspot.co.uk/2007/03/creating-dynamic-client-side-maps.html).

Comment: You don't even need to code per se to use the  google spreadsheets solution with google fusion tables (see [Google Fusion Tables - Create A Map](https://support.google.com/fusiontables/answer/2527132?hl=en&topic=2573107&ctx=topic))

Comment: cool the plot-link: http://gmaps.kaeding.name/saved/freifunk_nrw